# How to dynamically build multiple sites using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, controller

is it possible in MVC to setup a site where it would have one set of controllers but dynamically build the site based on a url that looked like this:

```
www.a.com/sitename/index
```

Each sitename would have it's own configuration, data, and look and feel.

Comment: "anything is possible". But your question is overly broad and off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could simply deploy the same MVC (or any) web application to separate virtual directories, each with their own configuration (and CSS files, etc.).

Alternatively, you could change the default route table to include {tenant} (which is what this is often called) as part of the path, and pick that up in your controllers.

Comment: The first would seems costly in time and money.  I like the alternate idea.  Could tenant be dynamically loaded from a table where I have all the site names? I want the user to create their site name and then it's ready for them to use just by changing the url. Seems like it maybe a performance issue unless I cashe it.

Comment: Not that costly in time or money. You'd automate deployment (you're doing that anyway, right?). The effort required for that is almost certainly less than that required to make your code tenant-aware. And virtual directories are free.

Comment: this seem plausable http://lukesampson.com/post/303245177/subdomains-for-a-single-application-with-asp-net-mvc